# Multiple observations per subject in logistic regressions

Tags: regression, logistic, repeated-measures

In my study, 210 subjects had to choose three out of nine options. I want to find out what several predictors (X1, X2, X3, X4) had on the selection of these options (Y), where:

- **X1** and **X2** are objective attributes of the options (i.e., independent
  from the subjects)
- **X3** is a subjective attribute of the options (i.e., specified for each
  option by each participant)
- **X4** is an attribute of the subject that in theory should influence the
  subjective importance of X1 and X2 for the selection decisions
- and **Y** shows for each option and each participant whether it was
  selected (1) or not (0).

My data thus looks like the following, with 210*9=1890 observations in total:

```
ID Y  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  1  1  1  10 5.5
1  0  2  1  56 5.5
1  1  3  1  25 5.5
1  1  1  2  11 5.5
1  0  2  2  14 5.5
1  0  3  2  23 5.5
1  0  1  3  25 5.5
1  0  2  3  45 5.5
1  0  3  3  47 5.5
2  0  1  1  22 4.9
2  1  2  1  25 4.9
2  0  3  1  27 4.9
...
```

My first idea was to calculate a logistic regression model where X1, X2, and X3 are used as predictors and X4 may interact with X1 and X2:

```
glm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X1:X4 + X2:X4, data = dat, family = binomial)
```

However, this neglects the multiple observations per participant. Does modelling the same model as a generalized estimating equation with ID as a clustering variable solve this problem?

Comment: Try the glmm package in r. Use subject as your random effect.

Comment: @josh that comment makes sense so long as all of your explanatory variables are uncorrelated with individual-level unobservables